# Grouping WHERE and AND as one satement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Im trying run this sql statement but its not working..

the select statement is ok but its just the bottom part that's giving me trouble.

```
SELECT VRVDIL.INVOICE_DATE,
    VRVDIL.INVOICE_NO,
    VRVDIL.DEAL_NO,
    VRVDIL.COST,
    VVD.DEAL_DATE,
    VVD.SALESMAN_NAME,
    VVD.SIGNED_DATE,
    VVD.STOCK_NO,
    VVD.VEHICLE_ID,
    VVD.VEHICLE_SALES_GROUP_DESCRIPTION,
    VVD.INVOICE_TO_NAME,
    VRVS.DATE_SOLD,
    VRVS.DAYS_IN_STOCK_BEFORE_SOLD,
    VRVS.LOCATION_NAME,
    VRVS.STOCKED_DATE,
    VRVS.VEHICLE_CLASS_DESCRIPTION,
    VRVRD.BUYER_NAME,
    VRVRD.PURCHASING_PRICE,
    VRVRD.SELLING_PRICE,
    VRV.VIN,
    VRV.VEHICLE_TYPE,
    VRV.REGO_NO,
    VRV.REGISTRATION_EXPIRY_DATE,
    VRV.MODEL_ID,
    VRV.MAKE_ID,
    VRVDOL.QTY
FROM VW_RG_VEHICLE_DEAL_INVOICE_LINE VRVDIL,
VW_VEHICLE_DEAL VVD,
VW_RG_VEHICLE_DEAL_ORDER_LINE VRVDOL,
VW_RG_VEHICLE VRV,
VW_RG_VEHICLE_STOCKCARD VRVS,
VW_RG_VEHICLE_REGISTER_DETAIL VRVRD
WHERE (VRVDIL.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY = VVD.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY
AND VRVDOL.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY = VVD.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY
AND VVD.VEHICLE_KEY = VRV.VEHICLE_KEY
AND VRVS.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY = VVD.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY
AND VRVS.VEHICLE_KEY = VRV.VEHICLE_KEY
AND VRVS.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY = VRVRD.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY
```

what is the error?

Comment: You did not close the parentheses and that may be error. Please note that it is always good to post on what type of error you are getting for better understanding.

Comment: So, what does the error says (assuming that you just missed the parenthesis on the question and not the query itself)

Comment: the database server is online so if the sql statement is incorrect it says database error..

Comment: how can I use parenthesis with the WHERE and AND clause?

Comment: The ending parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you miss a closing parenthesis?

```
WHERE (VRVDIL.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY = VVD.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY
AND VRVDOL.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY = VVD.VEHICLE_DEAL_KEY
AND VVD.VEHICLE_KEY = VRV.VEHICLE_KEY
AND VRVS.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY = VVD.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY
AND VRVS.VEHICLE_KEY = VRV.VEHICLE_KEY
AND VRVS.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY = VRVRD.VEHICLE_STOCKCARD_KEY)
```

At the end of the last `AND` condition, you should put a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that since the `WHERE` clause is all `AND`s, the parentheses aren't required at all.